# Formatting on onKeyUp() causing cursor to jump to end of input field

Tags: javascript, typescript, rendering, frontend

I am a newer front-end dev fresh out of college. This is my first time encountering an issue like this. I am working on a coworkers code so I don't want to change his code too much, simply fix an issue with his code without completely overhauling it.

We have 3 input style fields: input, phone, number

1. The input field is a free text field used for things like names.
2. The phone field is a number only field that formats number sequences into a 10 digit phone number with a (XXX)XXX-XXXX format in real time on the screen for the user.
3. The number field is used for things like ssn where only numbers are allowed. Non-numeric characters get rejected

All three of these fields extend a base format field. Inside this base format field, we have an onKeyUp(event: Event) function that calls a format function every time the user types a character. We do this to add things like the ( ) in the phone field as they type and remove non-numerical characters from the number fields as they type.

**HERE IS THE ISSUE**

By calling the format function on every keystroke our cursor is jumping to the end of the value in the input field after each keystroke. So if I have a pre-existing name in an input field: "John Smith" and I want to go back and edit that field to look something like "John Joe Smith" my cursor jumps to the end of the string after each keystroke.

My goal is to keep the formatting on keystroke so that phone numbers continue to be formatted and the number fields reject the non-numeric values in real time, but also I want to allow mid-value editing without kicking their cursor to the end of the value after each keystroke.

Is there a way to capture my cursor location before I call the format and then return my cursor location after the format? Or another solution that might be easily implemented?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the caret location from the element that triggers the event and then insert the text at that location using `substring`. Here's a snippet from a project of mine where I had to handle inserting tab characters (`\t`):

```
case 9: // Insert tab key at caret location
    e.preventDefault();
    var caret = e.target.selectionStart;
    e.target.value = e.target.value.substring(0, caret) + '\t' + e.target.value.substring(caret);
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I was able to use e.target.selectionStart to capture the caret location and set it in my element after my formatting, Thanks!

Comment: Pleasure. You can accept the answer so that people know it's the correct one without having to read comments. :)